# Keyboard lag so bad in Ubuntu 18.04 KDE

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, kde

I recently switched to KDE from Gnome in Ubuntu 18.04, and after 1 day, my keyboard lags so bad, it takes a while until the character I click appears on the screen and sometimes it repeats the character and sometimes the character didn't appear on the screen.
FYI:

- I use Ubuntu 18.04, KDE Plasma version 5.12.9
- My laptop is Acer Aspire-e-473g
- I have disabled slow keys and screen reader
- I am talking about my laptop's built-in keyboard

Please help me, let me know if I have to provide another information,  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by changing my driver to NVIDIA driver, updating the software, and lowering the animation speed in System Settings>Display and Monitor>Compositor, and then restarting my laptop. But I think the real answer was updating the software though.

EDIT : Idk why, but after somedays, this problem occur again. Please help me.